# drop1 function for lmer

Tags: r, lme4

I constructed a mixed effect model with three fixed effects and one random effect.

```
mdl1 <- lmer(yld.res ~ veg + rep + rip + (1|state),
       REML=FALSE,data=data2)
```

I want to get the most parsimonious model from the above model. To do this, I want to drop one independent variable at a time and see if it improved the fit of the model (by looking at the AICc value). But when I use `drop1`, it gives me the following error:

```
drop1(mdl1, test="F")

Error in match.arg(test) : 'arg' should be one of “none”, “Chisq”, “user”
```

I am not really sure how to go about this and would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just use `drop1()` with the default `test="none"` it will give you the AIC values corresponding to the model with each fixed effect dropped in turn.

Here's a slightly silly example (it probably doesn't make sense to test the model with a quadratic but no linear term):

```
library('lme4')
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + I(Days^2) + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
drop1(fm1)
## Single term deletions
## 
## Model:
## Reaction ~ Days + I(Days^2) + (Days | Subject)
##           Df    AIC
## <none>       1764.3
## Days       1 1769.2
## I(Days^2)  1 1763.9
```

How badly do you need `AICc` rather than `AIC`?  That could be tricky/require some hacking ...